# What does Function(params...)(params) do in python?

Tags: python, keras

I meet some Keras functions that look like the following : Function(1*List of parameters separated by commas)(2*A parameter). But I don't understand what does Function do on the second list of parameters. I have never met this kind of functions in Python. The usual type of functions' prototypes I see are of the following : Function(List of parameters)

Example of these functions met in Keras :

`x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.35)(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)`

In this case, it looks like that Function takes into account what was done precedently on x before applying on it new changes.

1. Is this kind of function writing backed by any Python manual ?
2. Is it a new type of function writing in Python ?
3. How does it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a function that returns a function which you immediately call. You can do the same:

```
def add(x):
    def add_x(y):
        return x + y
    return add_x
```

This function can now be called like this:

```
>>> add(4)(7)
11
```

---

This works because

> Functions are first-class objects. A “def” statement executed inside a function definition defines a local function that can be returned or passed around. Free variables used in the nested function can access the local variables of the function containing the def. [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

See also: [Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I see that the question was already asked elsewhere but formulated differently ! :D